# Non-exhaustive patterns with: Int -> Int -> [Film] -> [Film]

Tags: haskell

I want to make a function that returns a list of films in a given range of years. For example, given that i have a list of films, i want to find all the films that came out in the years 2010 to 2014. Here's my code:

```
type Rating = (String, Int)
type Title = String
type Director = String
type Year = Int
type Film = (Title, Director, Year,[Rating])

testDatabase :: [Film]
testDatabase = [("Blade Runner","Ridley Scott",1982,[("Amy",5), ("Bill",8), ("Ian",7), ("Kevin",9), ("Emma",4), ("Sam",7), ("Megan",4)]),
            ("The Fly","David Cronenberg",1986,[("Megan",4), ("Fred",7), ("Chris",5), ("Ian",0), ("Amy",6)]),
            ("Psycho","Alfred Hitchcock",1960,[("Bill",4), ("Jo",4), ("Garry",8), ("Kevin",7), ("Olga",8), ("Liz",10), ("Ian",9)]),
            ("Body Of Lies","Ridley Scott",2008,[("Sam",3), ("Neal",7), ("Kevin",2), ("Chris",5), ("Olga",6)]),
            ("Avatar","James Cameron",2009,[("Olga",1), ("Wally",8), ("Megan",9), ("Tim",5), ("Zoe",8), ("Emma",3)]),
            ("Titanic","James Cameron",1997,[("Zoe",7), ("Amy",1), ("Emma",5), ("Heidi",3), ("Jo",8), ("Megan",5), ("Olga",7), ("Tim",10)]),
            ("The Departed","Martin Scorsese",2006,[("Heidi",3), ("Jo",8), ("Megan",5), ("Tim",3), ("Fred",5)]),
            ("Aliens","Ridley Scott",1986,[("Fred",9), ("Dave",6), ("Amy",10), ("Bill",7), ("Wally",1), ("Zoe",5)]),
            ("Kingdom Of Heaven","Ridley Scott",2005,[("Garry",3), ("Chris",7), ("Emma",5), ("Bill",1), ("Dave",3)]),
            ("E.T. The Extra-Terrestrial","Steven Spielberg",1982,[("Ian",9), ("Amy",1), ("Emma",7), ("Sam",8), ("Wally",5), ("Zoe",6)]),
            ("Bridge of Spies","Steven Spielberg",2015,[("Fred",3), ("Garry",4), ("Amy",10), ("Bill",7), ("Wally",6)]),
            ("Vertigo","Alfred Hitchcock",1958,[("Bill",8), ("Emma",5), ("Garry",1), ("Kevin",6), ("Olga",6), ("Tim",10)]),
            ("The Birds","Alfred Hitchcock",1963,[("Garry",7), ("Kevin",8), ("Olga",4), ("Tim",8), ("Wally",3)]),
            ("Jaws","Steven Spielberg",1975,[("Fred",3), ("Garry",0), ("Jo",3), ("Neal",9), ("Emma",7)]),
            ("The Martian","Ridley Scott",2015,[("Emma",7), ("Sam",8), ("Wally",5), ("Dave",10)]),
            ("The Shawshank Redemption","Frank Darabont",1994,[("Jo",8), ("Sam",10), ("Zoe",4), ("Dave",7), ("Emma",3), ("Garry",10), ("Kevin",7)]),
            ("Gladiator","Ridley Scott",2000,[("Garry",7), ("Ian",4), ("Neal",5), ("Wally",3), ("Emma",4)]),
            ("The Green Mile","Frank Darabont",1999,[("Sam",3), ("Zoe",4), ("Dave",7), ("Wally",5), ("Jo",5)]),
            ("True Lies","James Cameron",1994,[("Dave",3), ("Kevin",10), ("Jo",0)]),
            ("Super 8","J J Abrams",2011,[("Dave",7), ("Wally",3), ("Garry",5), ("Megan",4)]),
            ("Minority Report","Steven Spielberg",2002,[("Dave",6), ("Garry",6), ("Megan",2), ("Sam",7), ("Wally",8)]),
            ("War Horse","Steven Spielberg",2011,[("Dave",6), ("Garry",6), ("Megan",3), ("Sam",7), ("Wally",8), ("Zoe",8)]),
            ("The Terminal","Steven Spielberg",2004,[("Olga",8), ("Heidi",8), ("Bill",2), ("Sam",6), ("Garry",8)]),
            ("Star Wars: The Force Awakens","J J Abrams",2015,[("Olga",6), ("Zoe",6), ("Bill",9), ("Sam",7), ("Wally",8), ("Emma",8)]),
            ("Hugo","Martin Scorsese",2011,[("Sam",9), ("Wally",3), ("Zoe",5), ("Liz",7)])]

filmsInRangeOfYears :: Int -> Int -> [Film] -> [Film]
filmsInRangeOfYears _ _ [] = []
filmsInRangeOfYears minYear maxYear [(title, director, year, rating)] = filter(\(_,_,year,_) -> year >= minYear && year <=maxYear) [(title, director, year, rating)]
```

However, i keep recieving this error

```
**Non-exhaustive patterns in function filmsInRangeOfYears**
```

After looking around online, i still do not understand how to fix this error; from what i understand i need more patterns to fill all the possible cases but the ones i used still gave me the same result. If anyone can help me this i will be very greatfull

edit: added a an example list of films

Comment: Can you think of an example input for `filmsInRangeOfYears` that wouldn't match either of the patterns that you have written?

Comment: @IanHenry hi how are you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused as to what you're trying to do here. I think this was your original intention:

```
filmsInRangeOfYears :: Int -> Int -> [Film] -> [Film]
filmsInRangeOfYears _ _ [] = []
filmsInRangeOfYears minYear maxYear ((title, director, year, rating):tail) = 
    if year >= minYear && year <= maxYear
    then (title, director, year, rating):filmsInRangeOfYears minYear maxYear tail
    else filmsInRangeOfYears minYear maxYear tail
```

There's no room for you to use `filter` in there. `filter` already does all that, so just turn your function into

```
filmsInRangeOfYears :: Int -> Int -> [Film] -> [Film]
filmsInRangeOfYears minYear maxYear films = filter (\(_,_,year,_) -> year >= minYear && year <=maxYear) films
```

Back to the cause of your error, to match lists exhaustively, you normally treat two cases:

```
a [] = ...
a (head:tail) = ...
```

That's the empty list and the non-empty list, matched as `head` and `tail`. These two patterns cover all the possible values a list may take. In your code, you wrote rules for the empty list and for a list with a single element in it, with that element's components matched to `title`, `director` and so on. You still had one more case left to treat, the one with a list of length >= 2.

Although, that would've still been wrong, considering the `filter` misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

In the first line:

```
filmsInRangeOfYears _ _ [] = []
```

you are matching against empty list. In the second line (omitting some details):

```
filmsInRangeOfYears minYear maxYear [(...)] = ...
```

you are matching against the list **consisting of one item**. You are missing the match against `x:xs`: head and non-empty tail.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

The problem here was that you were pattern matching for a singleton list.
When you call the function it first tries to match the pattern to the empty list, if not it moves onto the next pattern of the singleton list and if the list has more than one element it will move to the next pattern which in this case there is none thus causing the error.

**Solution**

```
filmsInRangeOfYears :: Int -> Int -> [Film] -> [Film]
filmsInRangeOfYears minYear maxYear = filter(\(_,_,year,_) -> year >= minYear && year <= maxYear)
```

**Explanation - Pattern Matching for two arguments when the type signature has three**

Because our function body is using the filter function that takes a predicate and a list if we only give it a predicate we will in return get a *partially applied function* this function is expecting a list just as our filmsInRangeOfYears function is as its last argument. This method is the same as doing the following. `filmsInRangeOfYears minYear maxYear xs = filter(...) xs`

Note we can also remove the empty list pattern matching because filter will return an empty list if no elements meet the predicate.